# Downmix from 5.1 Surround to two channel stereo using avconv

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, wmv, aac

I have a `.wmv` with the audio codec of `wmapro`, which my target video player chokes on. I am generally in the process to "standardise" my collection to x264/aac (as this works fine on all my devices), but this particular file gave me big trouble. I tried this:

```
avconv -i input.wmv -c:v libx264 -b:v 4800k -qmin 3 -qmax 69 -ar 44100 \
       -b:a 128k -c:a libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -pass 2 -y output.mp4
```

The first pass worked fine, but now I get the message

```
Resampling output channel count must be 1 or 2 for mono input; 1, 2 or 6 for
stereo input; or N for N channel input.
Can not resample 6 channels @ 48000 Hz to 2 channels @ 44100 Hz
```

And I googled all morning for this and only found "you got to downmix". I have tried `libmp3lame`, `ac3`, `acs3_fixed` and others, all get me this error.

If there is some options I got to give for this to work, I would very much like to know, as I couldn't find them and was not able to figure it out myself.

Thanks.

Comment: The first step is to use a recent [Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) and see if that does the job. Also, you should always include the complete console output.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is get HandBrakeCLI and do the following:

HandBrakeCLI -i file.wmv --preset Normal -o file.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it looks like the problem is that you are down-mixing and down-sampling (to 44100 Hz) at the same time. You should first down-mix to stereo @ 48000 Hz, then down-sample (or not).